# Make authorize controller to add a specified parameter during redirect to login page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

My IdentityServer4 `Authorize` controller upon authorization request for not logged user redirects to `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom"` all fine and dandy, however I need additional parameter in my query string(in URL) like this: `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom"&AnotherParameter="MyValue"`. It needs to be a separate parameter, `AnotherParameter` can't be contained in the `ReturnUrl` parameter's value in any way, so these are **not** solving the problem

- `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom&AnotherParameter=MyComputedValue"`
- `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom&acr_values=AnotherParameter:MyComputedValue"`

Is that possible?

**Short question containing all the details necessary to understand the problem:**  I want authorize controller to add a specified parameter during redirect to login page.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Pardon me please, but that's not the question, I don't have any problem with logging in or the flow itself, I need an additional parameter like stated in the question.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Does using `acr_values` on `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event lets me add parameter of name `AnotherParameter` to the query string that is not part of `ReturnUrl` parameter's value? If yes, then that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I found that `options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents() {
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => {
        context.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "urn:grn:authn:se:bankid:same-device";
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};` but I don't know if these acr_values end up in the query string like normal parameters(then it's great) or like I showed in the 2nd example that doesn't match the reuqirements :(.

Comment: acr_values need to be escaped, so it will be: `acr_values=AnotherParameter%3AMyComputedValue%20OtherParameter%3AOtherValue`

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I need a parameter of name `AnotherParmater` I show in the 2nd example in my question that contains these `acr_values` that this is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would help, but you could try to make the additional parameter a static part of the configured Login page URL. Something like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer((options) =>
{
    ...
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "~/Account/Login?AnotherParameter=MyValue";
    ...
});
```

You'd have to test it thoroughly though, as I don't think that this is by any means a "standard" way of doing things...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass a parameter to Identity Server ? You can try :

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
{

    n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("AnotherParameter", "MyComputedValue");

    await Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

On identity server side in `Login` method :

```
var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
var value = context.Parameters["AnotherParameter"];
```

**Update :**

Above solution will make parameter included in `redirect_uri` in authorization request .

If you want to outside the url  , like : `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom"&AnotherParameter="MyValue"` . Then you need to use `acr_values` or `state` which is correct parameter in [Oauth2/OIDC protocol](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthorizationEndpoint) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will the `AnotherParameter` be visible in the query string itself like stated in the question?

Comment: it will , try it

Comment: I will in 3 hours, thank you sincerely, I'll let you know how it will go.

Comment: I see that my last question wasn't precise enough, will it be a separate parameter passed to the `Login` page in the url, like that `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom"&AnotherParameter="MyValue"`.

Comment: I am confused about your issue . The request will be `/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=...&AnotherParameter=MyComputedValue&state=...&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0` .

Comment: Do you want to include the `otherParameter=MyComputedValue` in `redirect_uri` or do you want to make it outside the `redirect_uri` of the request ?

Comment: @Yoda , then No , use `acr_values` or `state` which is correct parameter in OIDC portal.

Comment: I want to have it outside ReturnUrl(not uri) when Authorize controller redirects to Login controller. I need `Login\ReturnUrl="WhereICameFrom"&AnotherParameter="MyValue"` when Authorize controller redirects to Login page

Comment: Yes, please read few words that preceed it: `, so these are not solving the problem`, I'll make them bold in next edit.

Comment: @d_f The question is really simple, it states the final state that I'd like to achieve I don't want to use any workarounds. I want authorize controller to add a specified parameter during redirect to login page.

Comment: so the solution for your "really simple question" is also simple: create a fork, insert a row before [the redirect](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/b5b122e7472dd8520eb49ee47152402831013379/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/Results/LoginPageResult.cs#L86). then delete this duplicate question. thanks! @Yoda

Comment: @d_f That is excellent( funny too : D ) answer, now I understand why it can't be done. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Yoda I'm glad you got it! wish you appreciated my initial answer : )